# C# - Save typed values

Tags: c#

I'm making a console program which you have to say how many students are in the class and how many tests you had on this class, so it'll give you at the end the student name with its final score. **The problem is that I can't make the final calculus=(sum/numberOfTests). It only take the last grade you told the program**. Here is the code.

```
namespace Repeat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //VARIABLES         
            float numberOfStudents;
            float numberOfTests;
            float average = 0;
            float grade;
            float sum = 0;
            string studentName;

            Console.WriteLine("Type the number of students");
            float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfStudents);
            Console.WriteLine("Type the number of tests");
            float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfTests);

            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfStudents; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Student name {0}: ", i);
                studentName = Console.ReadLine();

                for (int p = 1; p <= numberOfTests; p++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Test {0} grade: ", p);
                    float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade);

                    average = sum / numberOfTests;
                }

                if (average < 7)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Average: " + average);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else if (average >= 7)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Average: " + average);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            ///END
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set `sum` to anything, so `average` will always be 0 (0 / x == 0). You should be writing `sum += grade` before your average calculation

Answer (score 0):

actually you didn't set and update the `sum` value, so it was always `0`, fix your inner for loop like this

```
   sum = 0;
   for (int p = 1; p <= numberOfTests; p++)
   {
        Console.Write("Test {0} grade: ", p);
        float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade);
        sum = sum + grade;
        average = sum / numberOfTests;
   }
```

Comment: I have narrow down the code for better view where need to fix